# Difference between os.walk and glob.glob

Tags: python

The folder "documents" on my pc has 52150 files.

If I use this Python-code I get exactly the 52150 files:

```
import os

i = 0

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk('C:\\Users\\fibi\\Documents'):
    for filename in files:
        i += 1

print(i) # --> 52150
```

But if I use this code, which I thought it was the same, I only get 45180 files:

```
import glob

files = glob.glob('C:\\Users\\fibi\\Documents\\**\\*.*', recursive=True)

print(len(files)) # --> 45180
```

What ist the difference between the two?

Comment: Could be that not all of your files have a dot ('.') in them

Comment: maybe get all filenames from both methods and compare them to get differences - ie. using `set()`. And then you will see which filenames makes difference.  ie. `set(glob.glob('*')) - set(glob.glob('*.*'))`

Comment: on some systems you can use `*` instead of `*.*` to get all files. Some files may not have extension - so they don't have `.`